# IntelliJ IDEA 15 How to get rid of namespace information at the top of PHP and Sass code windows

Tags: intellij-idea

I just update to version 15 of IntelliJ IDEA and everything is working well, but they've added a new feature at the top of the code windows for PHP and Sass indicating the namespace or class I'm in.  I already know what namespace I'm in and what class/method/etc I'm working with so this just takes up room unnecessarily and when it changes I find it really distracting.

[image: Example of screen]

Anyone know what this is called so I can google how to remove it at least? I'd add the `intellij-15` tag, but I'm short in rep in order to add new tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Editor/General/Appearance* and uncheck *Show breadcrumbs*.