# IntelliJ: How to turn off XML/POM breadcrumbs

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Does anybody know how to turn off the XML/POM breadcrumbs line in IntelliJ? So that's the bit marked in red
[image: IntelliJ XML BreadCrumbs]

I don't want it as I just see this as visual clutter - I use the Structure window when I want to quickly navigate around an XML (or any other type of) file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA 15 How to get rid of namespace information at the top of PHP and Sass code windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485772/intellij-idea-15-how-to-get-rid-of-namespace-information-at-the-top-of-php-and-s)

Comment: @yole. Yep that's the solution although I'd never have found it by searching for PHP and Saas breadcrumbs (and it's different from the Java one)

If you want to submit as an answer I can mark it as correct.